# Bedeutung von "frei" in "Landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr frei"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Für mich, als Nichtmuttersprachler ist die Bedeutung des Wortes "frei" auf dem Verkehrsschild mit dem Hinweis

> "Landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr frei"

unklar.

Gibt es weitere, gute Beispiele, in denen das Wort auf gleiche Weise verwendet wird? Oder ist es eine Abkürzung eines vollständigen Satzes?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82613/discussion-on-question-by-igor-o-bedeutung-von-frei-in-landwirtschaftlicher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wollte man die Botschaft in deinem gelben Kasten zu einem ganzen Satz ausbauen, könnte man das auf eine der folgenden Arten:

> - Landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr **ist frei**, die Straße (oder das
>   Straßenstück) hinter dem Schild zu befahren.
> - Landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr **hat die Freiheit**, die Straße (oder das
>   Straßenstück) hinter dem Schild zu befahren.
> - Landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr **hat die Erlaubnis**, die Straße (oder das
>   Straßenstück) hinter dem Schild zu befahren.
> - Landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr **darf** die Straße (oder das
>   Straßenstück) hinter dem Schild befahren.

Wörtchen »frei« bedeutet in diesem Fall also so viel wie »von einem Verbot ausgenommen«.

Anderes Beispiel:

> Kinder bis 6 frei

Hängt ein Schild mit dieser Aufschrift am Eingang eines Zoos, heißt das, dass Kinder bis zu einem Alter von 6 Jahren von der Zahlungspflicht befreit sind. Die zahlen nix, können die Pforte ohne Weiteres passieren. Oder anders: Ein Loch im Zaun brauchst du erst ab 7.

Comment: Pollitzer, vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort und besonders für das Beispiel! Noch eine zusätzliche Frage: ist "Kinder bis 6 frei" ein richtiger, vollständiger Satz? Für mich sieht das immer noch nach einer sehr kurz gehaltenen Phrase, die man so formuliert hat, damit sie auf z.B. ein Schild passt.

Comment: Das Beispiel mit den Kindern halte ich nicht für zielführend. Es mag sein, dass die Formulierung *ursprünglich* einmal aus der Aussage entstanden ist, dass Kinder von der Bezahlpflicht ausgenommen sind. Jedoch hat sich die Bedeutung "frei = kostenlos" mittlerweile so verselbständigt, dass die Bedeutung "von einem Verbot/einer Pflicht ausgenommen" dabei eigentlich nicht mehr zum Tragen kommt.

Comment: @IgorO.: Nein, auch das ist kein vollständiger Satz. Auf Verkehrsschildern herrscht Platzmangel; am Zoo bevorzugt man vielleicht deshalb wenig Text (und damit kleine Schilder), um am Glaskasten nicht zu viel Sicht zu versperren oder um die [als Nebensache angesehene] Information nicht unnötig hervorzuheben.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: _»Kinder bis 6 frei«_ kann man auf zwei Arten interpretieren: (1) Kinder bis 6 müssen nichts zahlen (zahlungsbefreit), (2) Kinder bis 6 sind frei in Ihrer Bewegung Richtung Zoogelände, für sie gibt es keine Hürden (freier Durchgang).

Answer (score 3):

Das **Zusatzzeichen 1026-36: landwirtschaftlicher Verkehr frei**

[image: sign]

ist immer ein *Zusatz* zu einem Verkehrsschild mit einer definierten Bedeutung, häufig **Zeichen 250: Verbot für Fahrzeuge aller Art**:

[image: ![sign]

(Umgangssprachlich auch „Durchfahrt verboten“ genannt.)

*Frei* bedeutet in einem solchen Kontext, dass die genannte Gruppe nicht unter das Gebot/Verbot fällt, also frei von einer hier geltenden Beschränkung oder Pflicht ist.

Andere, allgemeinere Beispiele

- Eintritt X, Kinder unter 6 Jahren frei
  -> Der Zutritt ist kostenpflichtig, Kinder sind davon befreit. Dazu passend:
- Eintritt frei
  -> es gibt keine Zutrittsbeschränkung
- Freibetrag
  -> ein Geldbetrag, für den keine Steuern oder Abgaben erhoben werden, der also von der allgemein gültigen Pflicht hierzu befreit ist.
- Freigepäck
  -> eine bestimmte Anzahl an Gepäckstücken, für die im Gegensatz zu weiteren Koffern keine Transportgebühr erhoben wird. (Üblicherweise im Ticketpreis enthalten, daher eigentlich irreführend...)

---

Bildquelle: [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildtafel_der_Verkehrszeichen_in_der_Bundesrepublik_Deutschland_von_1992_bis_2013)

Answer (score 2):

"Frei" in all seinen Bedeutungen bedeutet im Grunde, dass etwas ohne Beschränkungen und Bedingungen ist, siehe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/frei unter **Bedeutungen**.

Darunter fallen dann alle Formen von Freiheit, körperliche, geistige, zeitliche und kreative. Auch Kostenfreiheit kann in dem Sinne verstanden werden, da es bedeutet, dass man eine Möglichkeit hat, die keine finanzielle Beschränkung aufweist.

In diesem Fall kann man das dann einfach so sehen, dass landwirtschaftlichem Verkehr keine Beschränkungen auferliegen.

Comment: Danke, Javatasse, der Link war hilfreich! Siehe meinen Kommentar oben zu meiner Frage.